# SetUp Apache VirtualHost (CentOs)

Tags: php, linux, apache

How to setup VirtualHost for new domain name on linux?
Just like,

- **http://weblog.localhost** -> direct to **/opt/lampp/htdocs/weblog.localhost/mvc_htdocs**

And, I added to this in **/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
> NameVirtualHost *:80
> 
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
>   ServerName localhost
> </VirtualHost>
> 
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/weblog.localhost/mvc_htdocs"
>   ServerName weblog.localhost
>   DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
> </VirtualHost>
```

I removed **#** front of **Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf** in **/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf**

But an empty website is appeared when I type my new domain.

Please give me a help. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new configuration file for this virtual host in "/etc/httpd/conf.d/". Create a new file vhost1.conf (You can choose any suitable name). Type code below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName weblog.localhost
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/weblog.localhost/mvc_htdocs
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Save and exit file. Restart httpd service.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Consider your project directory path is this 
       var/www/html/deepbase
    
    // If you are using only https then specify 
    //this tag <VirtualHost 10.77.22.110:443>(Domain Name:ssl port no.) only.
    
    // Restart Apache for the changes to take effect | very important point
    // systemctl restart httpd.service 
    
    //<VirtualHost *:443>
    <VirtualHost 10.77.22.110:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/25oct2021/wildcard_utiamc_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/25oct2021/private.key
        ServerName www.bop-uat.deepbase.com
        ServerAlias bop-uat.deepbase.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@deepbase.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/deepbase
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog /var/www/deepbase/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/deepbase/logs/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```